# How to compute edges intensity (edgeness factor) as texture feature

Tags: r, feature-extraction, focal-statistics, texture, edge-detection

I am trying to extract texture features from an image. I am interested in extracting the Mean and Standard Deviation of the edge intensity (edgeness factor). These texture measures were described by *Sutton and Hall* (1972) in **Texture Measures for Automatic Classification of Pulmonary Disease** DOI: 10.1109/T-C.1972.223572.

I found `Fetex2.0` software used in remote sensing applications for Object-Based Image Analysis. The reference paper, **Ruiz, L.A., Recio, J.A., Fernandez-Sarria, A. and Hermosilla, T. A feature extraction software tool for agricultural object-based image analysis** (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.compag.2011.02.007) contains the equations used to compute it. However, I would like to apply it using `Python` or `R` using a kernel (moving window) approach.

Any implementation or idea to compute these texture features using a kernel's convolution (moving window)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using `raster::focal` and *Laplacian* operators (2nd spatial derivative of the image).

For a distance of 1 pixel (*d = 1*):

```
edgeness_factor_d1 <- function(r){
  # Arguments:
  # r: RasterLayer used to compute edgeness factor
  # Value:
  # the function retuns the mean and standard deviation of edge intensity
  fx <- matrix(c(0, -1,  0, 
                -1,  4, -1, 
                 0, -1,  0), nrow=3)
  rx <- raster::focal(r, w=fx)
  fy <- replace(fx, values=1)
  rx_mean <- raster::focal(rx, w=fy, fun=mean)
  rx_stdv <- raster::focal(rx, w=fy, fun=sd)
  g <- raster::stack(rx_mean, rx_stdv)
  return(g)
}
```

for *d = 2*:

```
edgeness_factor_d2 <- function(r){
  # Arguments:
  # r: RasterLayer used to compute edgeness factor
  # Value:
  # the function retuns the mean and standard deviation of edge intensity
  fx <- matrix(c(0,  0, -1,  0,  0, 
                 0, -1, -2, -1,  0, 
                -1, -2, 16, -2, -1, 
                 0, -1, -2, -1,  0, 
                 0,  0, -1,  0,  0), nrow=5)
  rx <- raster::focal(r, w=fx)
  fy <- replace(fx, values=1)
  rx_mean <- raster::focal(rx, w=fy, fun=mean)
  rx_stdv <- raster::focal(rx, w=fy, fun=sd)
  g <- raster::stack(rx_mean, rx_stdv)
  return(g)
}
```